# how to insert url parameter into a google docs document like a template doc?

Tags: url, google-docs

i have a google docs (like a basic letter).
in this document i place strings like %parameter1% %parameter2% and %parameter3%.

is there a way to share this document and replace the strings %% by the value passed throught the url ?

in fact, i'd like (and i need) a way to have a online template document editor for a letter and fill it with only data from the url.

a way to perform action like : 
 https://docs.google.com/document/d/e/2PACX-1vRVioowRsxo6xDHXD3YtMgs0gEbgyA5bMmb4LXjEuJmNFq_he0czSoS98tqrLbg0NfDjV2pMMGcIHgZ/pub
+ **&parameter1=value1&parameter2=value2**

if google docs can't have this feature (url parameter for document filling), is there any other web solution to perform such action (so without installing anything software on computer)

thank you all for your advices and reading me.
Best regards